# KryoException Unable to find class Serialization trace

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I am using Kryo 5.2.0 and occasionally getting below exception. However, when I restart the tomcat then issue not happening, after some time it again throw this exception.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: Ethiopian Airlines
Serialization trace:
hmAdminAirInfo (com.biz.shared.airlines.AirlineInfoBean)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:182)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:151)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:758)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:869)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:226)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:42)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:796)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ReflectField.read(ReflectField.java:123)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:129)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:877)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:235)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:42)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:877)
        at com.tech.cacheengine.kryo.KryoUtil.deserialize(KryoUtil.java:104)
      
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ethiopian Airlines
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:176)
        ... 26 more
```

Kryo pool

```
private static final Pool<Kryo> kryoPool = new Pool<Kryo>(KRYO_INSTANCE_THREAD_SAFE, true, KRYO_POOL_MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        protected Kryo create() {
            final Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
            // kryo.setClassLoader(classLoader);
            kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false);
            // kryo.setWarnUnregisteredClasses(true);
            kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()));
            try {
                kryo.register(Class.forName("java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap"), new SynchronizedCollectionsSerializer());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SynchronizedCollectionsSerializer.registerSerializers(kryo);

            return kryo;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with kyro, but `Unable to find class: Ethiopian Airlines`. Why is it trying to lookup a class name with whitespace?

Comment: "Ethiopian Airlines" sin't a valid class name. The fact that Kryo is trying to create an instance of that class suggests that Kryo has encountered a data value when it was expecting a class name. The most likely cause of this is that the structure of the classes has changed since the serialised Kryo data was generated.

Comment: This kind of problem should be complemented by a minimal reproducer or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). so if you are able to condense your original project into something minimal (feel free to rename classes and packages) which still reveals the same problem, I am pretty sure that someone could help you. Not being a Kryo user, but knowing what it basically does, for now I suspect that you might be serialising something with Kryo version A, then trying to deserialise it with version B. But this is just an educated guess.

Comment: can you add a minimal reproducible example project?